# Generic Exception Handler Orchestration in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-orchestrations

Hi All BizTalk Developers,

I need some input and guidance on how to design an Orchestration that can take few parameters as Input and log them in SQL server table (tblTrackingData)

I want to start this orchestration at various points, for example when I am calling a webservice so I want to log the request in DB and when I get the response then I want to log the response xml also in the same table.

In case of any exception I want to log error message and other details in the same table for tracking purpose.

Can some one guide me, direct me to some existing blogs/posts on how to handle this generic tracking / exceptions etc by starting a new Orchestration.

The purpose of a new Orchestration is to call it from anywhere, please suggest if it could be handled in a better way also.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice, **don't do this.**

The reason?  *Everything* you describe is already done by BizTalk Server automatically by **BizTalk Tracking** and the **Event Log**.

I can tell you from experience, you will not need anything else beyond Tracking and the Event Log.

I do recommend you implement proper exception handling within you app and log custom events, but they would also be written to a **Windows Event Log only** as well.